# Show/Hide checkbox based on user choice from option list salesforce

Tags: html, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I have a form to add new user, inside that form I have a field where user pick from two values in option list and based on his choice I want to hide/show checkbox field.

So its goes like this:

```
     <template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Student__c">
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Name" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="First_name__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Last_name__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Email__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Address__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="EMSO__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="TypeOfStudy__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <template if:true={showBonus}>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Payer__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
            </lightning-input-field>
        </template>
<lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                          variant="brand"
                          name="save"
                          label="Save from createRecord"
                          onclick={saveForm}>
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

So `TypeOfStudy__c` is a option list, inside that list I have two values: `Full-time` - `Part-time`.

So if user select `part-time` the checkbox `Payer__c` should be displayed, otherwise is hidden.

I know In standard HTML I can assign for each option from the list value and then pass that value to the JS and based on value show/hide checkbox, but I got values from salesforce here, I'm not setting them manually, How I can access to user choice?

`JS`:

```
    import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    @track contactRecord = {};

    handleFieldChange(e) {
        this.contactRecord[e.currentTarget.fieldName] = e.target.value;
    }

    get showBonus() {
        return this.contactRecord != null && this.contactRecord.TypeOfStudy__c=== 'Part-Time';
    }

    saveForm() {
        // if(this.validated())
        console.log('Contact for save => ', JSON.stringify(this.contactRecord));
        createRecord({ apiName: CONTACT_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields: this.contactRecord })
            .then(contact => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Contact created from saveForm => ' + contact.id,
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error creating record',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }
    
}
```

[image]
[image]

And when I choose `Part-Time` checkbox doesnt appear

[image]

Comment: What's in your onchange and have you seen https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_conditional

Comment: So far I'm just saving record, it its `this.contactRecord[e.currentTarget.fieldName] = e.target.value;`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<template if:true={someExpression}>` around your `<lightning-input-field field-name="Bonus__c"` to show/hide it conditionally.

Unlike Aura and Visualforce - this expression will have to be "simple". No math or complex logic in it. It'll have to be a plain class variable (like your `this.contactRecord`) or a [getter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getters_setters)

JS

```js
get showBonus() {
    return this.contactRecord != null && this.contactRecord.TypeOfUser__c === 'Part-Time';
}
```

HTML

```html
<template if:true={showBonus}>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Bonus__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
</template>
```

(I used ["==="](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) so it has to be exact match, case sensitive etc)

P.S. Remember that this is just an UI thing, crafty user can tweak it. Do a server-side check too like a validation rule

Comment: Hi, thanks for help! I tried, but now my picklist dissapeard from form, I updated question with new html and js as you provided

Comment: I updated the question once more, Now I can see a pick list but when I choose a value from it checkbox doesnt appear on page

Comment: is the value in the picklist exactly what the code expects? "Part-Time", case sensitive, dash and so on?

Comment: Yes, check updated question again just to be sure.